# Question about polynomial $\sum_{j=1}^n j^k$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, polynomials, computational-complexity

How could I prove that
$ 1^k + 2^k + \cdots + n^k \in \Theta(n^{k+1}) $
or, equivalently,
$$ 0 < \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^k}{n^{k+1}} < \infty? $$
I would appreciate a hint rather than a solution. Thanks in advance. (*I am sorry if this question is duplicate, I've searched but didn't found anything similar*)

Comment: Try with [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)

Comment: __Hint:__ Show that it is a degree $k+1$ polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for searching first!  What if you think of $n^{k+1}$ as $n\cdot n^{k}$ and then think of multiplication by $n$ as "add n copies of this together".

Comment: It's pretty obvious that $$0<\sum_{i=1}^n i^k \leq n^{k+1}$$ That's a start :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That gives me that $\lim \sum i^k / n^{k+1} \leq 1< \infty$ but what about $0 < \lim \sum i^k / n^{k+1}$? Thanks for everything

Comment: @Max.P. Well, you don't even know that the limit exists, yet, so you only have $\limsup {\sum\dots} \leq 1$. But I did say, "That's a start."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about Riemann sums (if you want the precise value of the limit, else Thomas' estimation does it!)

Comment: Aw, I was about to post this :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Pew pew pew!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** One way you can do this is to bound the sum on either side by an integral.

The function $f(x)=x^k$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$; so, in particular, for each $j$ we have
$$
\int_{j-1}^{j}x^k\,dx\leq j^k\leq\int_{j}^{j+1}x^k\,dx
$$